# Comparing items in a list?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

If you have a list ( (1 4 5) 5 (6 2 5) ), and another list (5 1 3 7 5 (9 2 4) ), I need to write a procedure that compares items from the first list and sees if they're in the second. For example, (1 4 5) appears 0 times in (5 1 3 7 5 (9 2 3) ).  5 appears in this list 2 times, and (9 2 4) appears 0 times. So the list will return (0 2 0)

I need help writing a scheme procedure frequency that takes in two lists, the first being the one that has each component compared, and the second being the one that counts the number of occurrences of the first list. The procedure should return a list of the occurrences.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a homework, so I won't give you a straight answer. Instead, I'll point you in the right direction. For starters, split the problem in two procedures:

- The first procedure, let's call it `counter`, receives an element and a list of elements. It traverses the list of elements asking, for each of them, if it's equal to the element passed as parameter. It adds one to the accumulated result if a match is found or continues with the next element if not. The list traversal ends when the null list is reached, and for this the counter returns zero.
- The second procedure, called `frequency` receives the two lists in the question and traverses the first list (the list of elements to compare against). For each of those elements, it calls `counter` to find out the result, building up a list along the way.

Here's the general structure of the solution, you must fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (counter ele lst)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         <???>)
        ((equal? ele <???>)
         (<???> (counter ele <???>)))
        (else
         (counter ele <???>))))

(define (frequency els lst)
  (if (null? els)
      <???>
      (cons <???>
            (frequency <???> lst))))
```

Notice that in `counter` I'm assuming that the element is being searched at the base level in the list, for instance this won't find the element:

```
(counter 5 '((5)))
=> 0
```

If you have to find matches like the one on the above example, then the problem is a bit more interesting - you'll need to recursively traverse the list of lists in a tree-like fashion. There are countless examples of that in Stack Overflow or elsewhere in Internet; if you're feeling a bit lost I'd recommend you take a look at either [The Little Schemer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262560992) or [How to Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), both books will teach you how to grok recursive processes in general.

Answer (score 0):

usually i would solve this with a method in the template list

```
template<class t>
class list
{
   bool contains( t obj )
   {
   for( int i = 0; i < this->size; i++ )
      if( this->at(i) == obj )
         return true;
   } 
}
```

i hope this will help you ;)

Comment: Is your use of c++ to answer a Scheme question a subtle dig at him for not doing his homework?