# Comparing items in a list? scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

If you have a list ( (1 4 5) 5 (6 2 5) ), and another list (5 1 3 7 5 (9 2 4) ), I need to write a procedure that compares items from the first list and sees if they're in the second. For example, (1 4 5) appears 0 times in (5 1 3 7 5 (9 2 3) ). 5 appears in this list 2 times, and (9 2 4) appears 0 times. So the list will return (0 2 0)

I need help writing a scheme procedure frequency that takes in two lists, the first being the one that has each component compared, and the second being the one that counts the number of occurrences of the first list. The procedure should return a list of the occurrences.

So far I've been told to make two procedures, one that counts the occurrences (counter) for each item and the other that keeps track of it in a list (frequency). I've done this so far:

`(define (counter ele lst)`

```
 `(cond ((null? lst)  `                          
       '()) 
        `((equal? ele lst)`                
            `(+ 1 (counter ele (cdr lst))))`    
        `(else`
        `(counter ele (cdr lst)))))`
```

`(define (frequency els lst)`

```
 `(if (null? els)` 
      `'()`
      `(cons <???>`
      `(frequency <???> lst))))`
```

I'm not sure what to do with the frequency procedure, and how to call the counter procedure from it

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing items in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233232/comparing-items-in-a-list)

Comment: I can't believe this. The last time you posted this question I gave you all the hints necessary to solve it, and you haven't made the smallest effort to try! you just posted _my own answer_ hoping for someone else to fill the blanks for you!

Comment: You've already more or less described, in English, what should fill in the blanks. Your next task isn't going to get any easier by your cheating your way through this one.

Answer (score 1):

For something like this you are going to have to use something like pair? becuase you working with trees which are lists of lists.

For example the car of (list (list 1 2) 3 4) is going to be the list 1 2. So that means if you try to compare values you will get an error. You need to isolate the leaves (the individual numbers) from the pairs to be able to compare.